# ASP.NET CommandField & skin

Tags: asp.net, skin, commandfield

I'm tying to skin ASP.NET GridView CommandField. 
Everything si working fine, just when I move CommandField property declarations from page to skin file, the whole commandField properties are ignored. here is my skin file:

```
<asp:GridView 
AllowPaging="true" 
AllowSorting="false" 
AutoGenerateEditButton="false" 
AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" 
AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
GridLines="None" 
PageSize="20" 
ShowFooter="false" 
ShowHeader="true" 
runat="server"> 
<Columns> 

<asp:CommandField 
ButtonType="Image" 
ControlStyle-Width="25" 
EditImageUrl="Images/Icons/pencil.png" 
DeleteImageUrl="Images/Icons/cross.png" 
/> 

</Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

In web.config I apply only StyleSheetTheme. Do I miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a **Fontawesome** icon, you can change it like that:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" ShowEditButton="true"
EditText="<i class='fas fa-edit'></i>" />
```

for Delete use:

```
DeleteText="<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>"
```

for Canel use:

```
CancelText="<i class='fas fa-window-close'></i>"
```

for Update use:

```
UpdateText="<i class='fas fa-sync'></i>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I get:

Content of literal

```
<asp:CommandField
ButtonType="Image"
ShowDeleteButton="true"
ItemStyle-Width="25"
DeleteImageUrl="~/App_Themes/SimplaAdmin/Images/Icons/cross.png"
/>
```

is not allowed within a skin file.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using StyleSheetTheme and NOT Theme.

Following is the control style defined in a .skin file

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" Font-Names="verdana,arial,sans serif" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="95%">
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" CancelImageUrl="~/Images/Buttons/16x16/Cancel.gif"
        EditImageUrl="~/Images/Buttons/16x16/Edit.gif" ShowEditButton="True" InsertImageUrl="~/Images/Buttons/16x16/New.gif" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/Buttons/16x16/Update.gif" />

    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/Buttons/16x16/Delete.gif"
        ShowDeleteButton="True" />
</Columns>

<RowStyle Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="Black" />
<PagerStyle Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="Black" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#2D5C3D" Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="left" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#2D5C3D" />
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#2D5C3D" />
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ECE9D8" />
```

The web.config file defines the StyleSheetTheme as site level

```
<pages styleSheetTheme="Green" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
```

The .aspx page containing the GridView control

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvUser" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="Id" onpageindexchanged="gvUser_PageIndexChanged" 
    onpageindexchanging="gvUser_PageIndexChanging" 
    onrowcancelingedit="gvUser_RowCancelingEdit" onrowdeleting="gvUser_RowDeleting" 
    onrowediting="gvUser_RowEditing" onrowupdating="gvUser_RowUpdating" 
    onselectedindexchanging="gvUser_SelectedIndexChanging" onsorted="gvUser_Sorted" 
    onsorting="gvUser_Sorting">

    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="User Id" >
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>


    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

For detail please refer to the following

1. http://weblogs.asp.net/vimodi/ThemesFaqs
2. http://weblogs.asp.net/vimodi/WhatIs-StyleSheetTheme

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you move the CommandField tag outside of the GridView tag?

i.e.:

```
<asp:GridView 
AllowPaging="true" 
AllowSorting="false" 
AutoGenerateEditButton="false" 
AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false" 
AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
GridLines="None" 
PageSize="20" 
ShowFooter="false" 
ShowHeader="true" 
runat="server"> 
</asp:GridView> 

<asp:CommandField 
ButtonType="Image" 
ControlStyle-Width="25" 
EditImageUrl="Images/Icons/pencil.png" 
DeleteImageUrl="Images/Icons/cross.png" 
/>
```